# PhantomJS: NPM is installing locally even if same version is on global

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I have PhanthomJS installed globally and when I'm running 'npm install' in a local project it is still trying to download PhantomJS from Bitbucket and install locally. Is there a way to avoid this extra download as PhantomJS is already available globally? I made sure that it was the same version being installed.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "testApp",
  "devDependencies": {
    ....
    "karma": "~0.12",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.2.6",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.9.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Normally the download doesn't happen, because the binary/zip package is in the cache.

Comment: I see this in the logs... Looks like an `npm install -g`; unable to check for already installed version.

Comment: I see the same in the logs of our build servers (running RHEL).  I tried fixing the file permissions under /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs - the module was globally installed as root, and the permissions were unnecessarily restrictive to ordinary users.  Unfortunately, this still didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the same issue myself.  I've also set the 'PHANTOMJS_BIN' variable to that of the globally installed phantomjs but still didn't get anywhere.

The only thing that I tried and works is by using this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-phantomjs-launcher-nonet

Only issue is that you have to set the paths to the global installed exe which may change per user

Answer (score 0):

Installing Phantom on a global level didn't help me either. Here is what I did on a windows machine

- Download phantomjs-windows-{version no}-windows.zip from https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads
- Extract the zip file to C:\PhantomJs
- Set the PATH environment variable point to phantomjs.exe. In this case add C:\PhantomJs\bin to PATH. Also create a new system environment variable "PHANTOMJS_BIN" and point it to the same location
- Check that it works by going to command prompt and run "phantomjs --version"